# Why is my plot so small?

Tags: plotting

This code

```
e12 = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82, 100};
l12 = Log[e12];
l12m = Log[e12 0.9];
l12p = Log[e12 1.1];
LogLinearPlot[{}, {r, 10, 100}, Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {e12},
  PlotRange -> {0, 80},
  Epilog ->  {{Table[{Dashed, Line[{{l12[[r1]], 0}, {l12[[r1]], 100}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]},
    {Table[{Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 5 + 5 r1}, {l12p[[r1]], 5 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]},
    {Table[{Blue, Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 2}, {l12p[[r1]], 2}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]},
    {Table[{Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 3.75 + 5 r1}, {l12m[[r1]], 6.25 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]},
    {Table[{Line[{{l12p[[r1]], 3.75 + 5 r1}, {l12p[[r1]], 6.25 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]}
  }]
```

gives me this plot:

[image]

Any idea why it's so small?

Comment: In version 7 I get no errors and a plot of normal dimension.  What version are you using?  Presumably your empty-body usage wasn't designed for.  Try plotting *something* but styling it white or transparent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I'm using version 9. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "try plotting something...".

Comment: In version 9 I have no problem either. To increase the size of the plot you can add the option "ImageSize".

Comment: I meant that you are not plotting anything in the body of `LogLinearPlot`; you are only using it ancillary fashion get logarithmic scaling.  Possibly using e.g. `LogLinearPlot[10, {r, 10, 100}, PlotStyle -> Transparent, . . .` will help.  Since I don't have the problem I can't test it, and since Kardashev3 also does not have the problem this might have to do with your local configuration.

Comment: I get an error: "ListQ::argx: ListQ called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>" (version 9.0.1 on MacOS X 10.90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sequence @@ {}` and not `{}` and the size of the image can be controlled using `ImageSize`. Also look at `ImageMargins` and `ImagePadding` for more control of layout

```
e12 = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82, 100};
l12 = Log[e12];
l12m = Log[e12 0.9];
l12p = Log[e12 1.1];
LogLinearPlot[Sequence @@ {}, {r, 10, 100}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
 Ticks -> {e12}, PlotRange -> {0, 80}, 
 Epilog -> {{Table[{Dashed, 
      Line[{{l12[[r1]], 0}, {l12[[r1]], 100}}]}, {r1, 1, 
      13}]}, {Table[{Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 5 + 5 r1}, {l12p[[r1]], 
         5 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]}, {Table[{Blue, 
      Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 2}, {l12p[[r1]], 2}}]}, {r1, 1, 
      13}]}, {Table[{Line[{{l12m[[r1]], 3.75 + 5 r1}, {l12m[[r1]], 
         6.25 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 
      13}]}, {Table[{Line[{{l12p[[r1]], 3.75 + 5 r1}, {l12p[[r1]], 
         6.25 + 5 r1}}]}, {r1, 1, 13}]}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Let run r like {r, 9, 105} to have all bars fully shown at the margins.